# Is parseInt() supposed to work like this?

Tags: javascript

If I write this script :

`alert(parseInt("123blahblahblah456"));`

I get the alert with the value `123`

Ideally, shouldn't the function NOT do anything since it is an invalid integer string?
Similar is the case with `parseFloat()`

Comment: Handy Google search tip: enter "mdn" after the name of a JavaScript function, e.g., "parseint mdn", and the first search result is almost always the appropriate doco page at the Mozilla Developer Network.

Comment: This behavior becomes handy when you are parsing CSS properties since sometimes, they include a unit: `parseInt("120px",10)` -> `120`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes: `parseInt()` is absolutely meant to work like that; to quote the Mozilla Developer Network entry:

> The parseInt function converts its first argument to a string, parses it, and returns an integer or NaN. If not NaN, the returned value will be the decimal integer representation of the first argument taken as a number in the specified radix (base). For example, a radix of 10 indicates to convert from a decimal number, 8 octal, 16 hexadecimal, and so on. For radices above 10, the letters of the alphabet indicate numerals greater than 9. For example, for hexadecimal numbers (base 16), A through F are used.
>
> If parseInt encounters a character that is not a numeral in the specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and returns the integer value parsed up to that point. parseInt truncates numbers to integer values. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed.

It seems that `parseInt()` is explicitly expecting to take a string and will take the first sequence of numbers (until it encounters an invalid numerical character) and return that as a number of whatever base was specified in the radix parameter.

Incidentally, to reduce errors when parsing the strings passed to `parseInt()` remember to use the radix parameter, for example:

```
parseInt('123odod24',10); // for base-10
parseInt('123odod24',16); // for base-16
```

Reference:

- [`parseInt()` at the MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Comment: this is pretty stupid, I get that it might have some useful applications but it would be far more useful if it could just check the entire string and return false if it encountered anything that was NaN. Just to be clear I'm calling Brendan Eich stupid for making this decision, not you :)

Answer (score 20):

Yes, cf all the anwers. I'd like to add that this is why checking if certain value can be converted to a number, it's better to use `Number` or just `+`.

```
Number("123blahblahblah456"); //=> NaN
Number("123"); //=> 123
+"97.221" //=> 97.221
// if the conversion result needs to be an int
Math.round(Number("123.4567")); //=> 123
```

Be aware though that `Number` in some cases (unexpectely) returns `0`.

```
+null   //=> 0
+"  "   //=> 0
+""     //=> 0
+false  //=> 0
+[]     //=> 0
```

Answer (score 13):

`parseInt` attempts to parse the string until it finds a non-integer value, at which point it returns whatever it had.

So if the string is:

- 1234abcd - it returns 1234
- 1a3f - it returns 1
- a14883 - it returns NaN
- 1.5 - it returns 1
- -1.3a - it returns -1

Same with `parseFloat` except that won't break on a `.`

- 1234abcd - it returns 1234
- 1a3f - it returns 1
- a14883 - it returns NaN
- 1.5 - it returns 1.5
- -1.3a - it returns -1.3

Answer (score 6):

This is how it is suppose to work. It parse the string until it reaches a non numerical character.

You might be interested in checking out the function `isFinite()`, it checks wether a string is a finite, legal number:

```
isFinite("123"); // true
isFinite("123a");// false
```

However this will return true for empty string and whitespace. You can therefore improve this solution by writing

```
mystring = "123";
mystringb = " ";
!isNaN(parseInt(mystring)) && isFinite(mystring); // true
!isNaN(parseInt(mystringb)) && isFinite(mystringb); // false
```

Based on these suggestions I'm sure you can build your own function that will ignore any string that contains nonnumerical characters.

Comment: Just beware IE11 doesn't support isFinite fn

Answer (score 3):

It's [documented to behave like that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Description):

> If `parseInt` encounters a character that is not a numeral in the
>   specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and
>   returns the integer value parsed up to that point.

Whether that behaviour is a good idea is another matter, but it's too late to change it now.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the `parseInt()` method is trying to parse until it finds a character. So if you have

- `parseInt("123 Iam funny")` it will return 123.
- `parseInt("whats up 4711")` it will return NaN

Some documentation you might be checking out :

- http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/parseint.html
- http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2012-Exploring-Javascript-s-parseInt-And-parseFloat-Functions.htm

Answer (score -2):

yes ! like explain here : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp

> Tips and Notes
>
> Note: Only the first number in the string is returned!
>
> Note: Leading and trailing spaces are allowed.
>
> Note: If the first character cannot be converted to a number,
>   parseInt() returns NaN.

Example

Parse different strings:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

document.write(parseInt("10") + "<br />");
document.write(parseInt("10.33") + "<br />");
document.write(parseInt("34 45 66") + "<br />");
document.write(parseInt(" 60 ") + "<br />");
document.write(parseInt("40 years") + "<br />");
document.write(parseInt("He was 40") + "<br />");

document.write("<br />");
document.write(parseInt("10",10)+ "<br />");
document.write(parseInt("010")+ "<br />");
document.write(parseInt("10",8)+ "<br />");
document.write(parseInt("0x10")+ "<br />");
document.write(parseInt("10",16)+ "<br />");

</script>
```

The output of the code above will be:

```
10
10
34
60
40
NaN

10
8
8
16
16
```