# How to convert non numeric string to int

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

For an assignment, i am trying to recreate a small project I once made in ASP.NET.

It converted each letter of a text to its `int` value, then added 1 en reconverted it to a `char` and put them all back into a single string.

Now I am trying to do this in Angular, but I am having trouble converting my non-numeric strings to its `int` value.

I tried it with `ParseInt()`, but this only seems to work if the string is a valid integer.

Is there any way to parse or convert non-numeric strings to an int value and how?

Comment: Look here : [ParseInt on letters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9429113/is-parseint-supposed-to-work-like-this)

Comment: it seems like you will have to do the same thing you have done in your ASP.NET program;  break your string into an array of `char`, then loop through the array and use `char.charCodeAt()` on each letter.

Comment: @Claies In ASP.NET I was simply doing `(int)stringmsg[i]` in a for loop, but the charCodeAt put me on the right track, so thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thankx to the helpful insights of [Claies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2495283/claies) and [Damien Czapiewski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1274664/damian-czapiewski) I constructed the following solution.

Loop through each character in my `string` in a `for loop`.
Then, for each `char` I retrieved its value with `charCodeAt()`
And to return to a `string` value I used `fromCharCode()`

```
encode(msg:string):string {

    let result: string = "";

    if (msg) {
        for (var i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {

            let msgToInt = msg.charCodeAt(i);

           // do stuff here

            result += String.fromCharCode(msgToInt);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
'String here'.split('').map(function (char) {
    return String.fromCharCode(char.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
}).join('');
```

If you mean char code.

Comment: This is probably good for Javascript, but i'm looking for an Angular/Typescript syntax solution. Perhaps the javascript tag should be removed from the question.. But this and @Claies comment helped me